# Couples Problems (Unions of Perfect Matchings)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

You are at a party with $n$ couples. You have been introduced to all the couples, remember all the attendants of the party who belong to couples, but you may not remember everything about which pairs are couples (we can exclude and your date from the $2n$ people in couples, if you brought one, as if you do not remember that, you have a bigger problem than this one). In any case, you have a set of possible couples according to your subjective remembering. These are edges attaching vertices that are attendants in couples. But, with the information available to you, not all graphs on these vertices are possible. The condition is that your graph must be a union of a non-zero number of perfect matchings of its $2n$ vertices. For example, a graph with no edges is not allowed because it has no perfect matchings. A path graph on more than two vertices is not allowed because there is a vertex $v$ with degree one connected to a vertex $w$ of degree two. $v$ must be matched with $w$ under any arrangement of couples you believe to be possible, but then the other edge out of $w$ cannot be used in a perfect matching. When every vertex of degree greater than one is connected only to such vertices, we still may have a problem. Consider a bipartite graph with on part the vertices $(0,a)$ and the other part vertices $(1,a)$ with $a$ ranging from one to five in both cases. Take all and only edges with vertices $(b,1)$ and $(b,2)$ for $b=0,1$. This cannot work because once we have chosen at most four edges for the vertices $(b,1)$ or $(b,2)$, we still must have at least two unmatched vertices. (Technical detail: if you are rational in the game-theoretic sense, then the actual matching should belong to your graph, but we'll either ignore this detail, or count over all possible actual matchings.) How many ways can you remember who's with who? Is there any nice description of these graphs?

Comment: This... seems more like a Q for puzzling.stackexchange.com perhaps? I'm not certain. Also are we looking for the size of the set of possible pairings? (A quick sketch shows this is $(2n-1)!!$, where $!!$ is the double-factorial.) Or is there something else you're looking for?

Comment: You (in the problem) may have forgotten something about the actual perfect matching. So you have a graph of all the edges that you subjectively think might possibly be couples. Formally, the property is that the graph is a union of one or more perfect matchings, each you regard as a possibility. Not every graph with a perfect matching has this property. For a trivial example, take a path graph.

Comment: What do you mean by "perfect matchings"?

Comment: Can the question be summarized as "Characterize graphs obtained by taking the union of several perfect matchings on the same set of $2n$ vertices"?

Comment: Yes. characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since admissible graphs are unions of perfect matchings, a *poly-time* way to test whether a graph is admissible is to check whether every edge is in a perfect matching – remove the vertices incident to the edge being tested, then check whether the remainder has a perfect matching. In my view this is a sufficient characterisation.

Comment: I never said the matchings were disjoint, and that doesn't make sense in the setting of the question. The graphs do not have to be regular. For example, take an isolated edge and a box.